# select option selection in php

Tags: php, html-select

I have a form for input order, there are 2 fields, branch and customer model. Before we click button "search", we must select branch and customer fields. After I filled the field, then click button search, the data appears. The problem is, after the data appears, where the condition branch and customer models are filled, I want to create another search, then I changed branch field only (customer model field was same with the previous search), change branch field from 'A' to 'B' and click button search, the data not appears / empty (whereas the data exists in database). Branch field,the field when I changed into B, after I click button search, the branch filled changed into

> `'SELECT'` (branch option are SELECT -> A , B).

I'm confused with this problem.. here is the code :

```
<?php
   if ($_POST)
   {
      $_SESSION['data_id'] = $_POST['data_id'];
      $_SESSION['branch'] = $_POST['branch'];
      $_SESSION['customer_model'] = $_POST['customer_model'];
    }
 ?>
 <form id="search" class="formular" method="post" action="search_data.php" style="z-index:1;">
   <table width="100%">
     <tr>
       <td>Data ID :</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="data_id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['data_id'];?>"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <?php
            $branch = "'".str_replace(",", "','", $_SESSION['moi_status_UserBranch'])."'";
            $check_data = $db->GetAll("select cab_id, cabang_name from company_profile where cab_id in(".$branch.")");
        ?>
        <td>Branch :</td>
        <td>
            <select id="branch" name="branch">
                    <option value="0">Select</option>
                <?php foreach($check_data as $row): ?>
                    <option <?php echo ($_SESSION['branch'] == $row['CAB_ID']) ? "selected" : ""; ?> value="<?php echo $row['CAB_ID']; ?>"><?php echo $row['CABANG_NAME']; ?></option>
                <?php endForeach; ?>
            </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="110">Customer Model</td>
        <td>
            <select id="customer_model" name="customer_model" class="readonly validate[required]">
                <option <?php echo ($_SESSION['customer_model'] == '0') ? "selected" : ""; ?> value="0">Pilih</option>
                <option <?php echo ($_SESSION['customer_model'] == 'I') ? "selected" : ""; ?> value="I">Personal</option>
                <option <?php echo ($_SESSION['customer_model'] == 'C') ? "selected" : ""; ?> value="C">Corporate</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" id="btnsubmits" name="btnsubmit" class="button" value="Search" />
<a onclick="mypopup();" style="text-decoration:underline; cursor:pointer; font-weight:bolder">Add New</a>
</form>
<script>
function mypopup()
   {
      <?php unset($_SESSION['regional_saved']); ?>
      mywindow = window.open("choose_custtype.php" ,"Item","width=700px,height=350px,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,top=150,left=200");
      mywindow.moveTo(200, 200);
   }
```